# How to show the chat icon for Excel desktop application?

Tags: excel, office365

According to Microsoft Help: [Enhance collaboration with Chat in Microsoft Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enhance-collaboration-with-chat-in-microsoft-office-1ecc6c7f-0b02-4baa-b9d9-c9d67023bedd). I would expect to see the chat icon for Excel Desktop application, but I don't:

[image: no chat icon]

I am using Microsoft Office 3654 ProPlus. I have access to the chat window using this workaround:

[image: how to access to the chat]

Searching online, I found a similar problem, but for Excel online: [Unable to find "chat" button when co-authoring excel online](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_online/unable-to-find-chat-button-when-co-authoring-excel/7a43565e-d61b-4030-bed8-3a5c908c9488), but my issue is only with Excel Desktop application. I am able to see the chat icon with Excel online.

I was trying to add it to the Ribbon or Quick Access Toolbar, but that feature does not belong to such sections of the excel header. I am pretty sure its something easy, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft, they eliminated the chat button for Excel Desktop App although the Excel Office Online has this option. Now they offer to access to chat function (Join Chat Group) in the way it is explained in the question. Microsoft calls it: "a design change".

So far it happens for the following version:

- version 1907(Build 11901.20218)
- version 1908(Build 11929.20254) latest one

For more information, please check the [response for a similar question in Microsoft Community Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-show-the-chat-icon-for-excel-desktop/06af3da3-df48-4c4a-b40a-731b447e6add).

If you don't like it, the only option is to dislike this feature (`File->Feedback`) from Excel Desktop application.